# Record Linkage: Comparing String Comparators

Tags: string, comparison, record, comparator, linkage

I am working on record linkage project, and I need to do some investigation work on a variety of string comparators.  The one's I'm looking at are:

Jaro-Winkler, Levenshtein Distance, Longest Common Substring, and Exact Match.

I'm wondering, has any work been done to determine which is good to use and when?  That is, Jaro-Winkler seems like it's good for names, but it might be better to do an exact match on social security numbers.  Which would you use for addresses?  Are there advantages to Jaro-Winkler over the others?

Are there any white papers out there someone could point me to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point is the paper ['A Comparison of String Distance Metrics for Name-Matching Tasks'](http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/doc/iiweb03.pdf) of [William W. Cohen](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wcohen/) et al. The paper compares several string distance metrics.

They also implemented the most of them within within the [SecondString project](http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/). It is a "open-source Java-based package of approximate string-matching techniques" so you could easily compare the different metrics without implementing everything by yourself.

It is nearly impossible to say which metric is the best. As you say, Jaro-Winkler is good for names, to compare adresses it could make sense to use token based metrics like TFIDF or SoftTFIFD like described by Cohen.

To be able to make an decision you should also consider the complexity of the underlying algorithms and the associated execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out google scholar found this paper

http://www.amstat.org/sections/srms/Proceedings/y2006/Files/JSM2006-000855.pdf

Comment: It would be better to summarize the contents of the paper in the answer rather than posting a link-only answer.  This link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

For names, particularly English language surnames, the Caverphone algorithm is well worth a look. I tested several on my dataset and it performed best - for my needs at least.